# Generic distinction

Tags: c#, generics

I have two interfaces

```
public interface IEntity<TKey> {
}
```

and

```
public interface IEntity : IEntity<int> {
}
```

I know I can check if a type is `IEntity` by doing `if ( entity is IEntity )` but how can I check if it's more generally an `IEntity<TKey>` object?

Also, how can i cast safely the generic entity to the interface type?

Comment: You need to clarify that last part about the cast

Comment: Nevermind. Your answer gave me the idea! :) thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the following example using reflection.

```
Type targetType = typeof(IEntity<>);
var entityType = entity.GetType();
if (entityType.IsGenericType 
    && targetType.IsAssignableFrom(entityType.GetGenericTypeDefinition())) {

}
```